# Unsure in how to type my function in haskell

Tags: haskell, fibonacci

```
nFibbo :: [x] -> [x]
nFibbo x = x ++ sum x
```

I'm trying to setup a Fibonacci function and I want the input to be an integer array of indeterminate length and it's output to be an integer array of 1+ the length of the first.

I have tried just not typing it at all and running

```
nFibbo x = x ++ sum x
```

But that shows up with a different error "cannot construct the infinite type: `a ~ [a]`"

Comment: This error comes up _a lot_ on Stackoverflow. And it's _always_ because a value is being used in place of a list or vice versa. Here is an example search that could have led you to an answer without having to ask your own question: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bhaskell%5D+%22cannot+construct+the+infinite+type%22+list

Comment: @PeterHall ouch.  Would OP know how to generalize the answers from those questions and apply to his own?

Comment: @luqui There was actually an almost identical question very recently with `++` being given a list on one side and a value on the other. It might have been deleted and I don't have the rep to see it. Given that I can't find that exact question now, perhaps it is a little harsh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well that's quite weird, since:

if `x` is an array `[a]`, then `sum x` will be an `a`. The `(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]` function takes two lists, not a list and an element.

You can however **construct a list with one element**, for instance using list syntax:

```
nFibbo :: Num x => [x] -> [x]
nFibbo x = x ++ [sum x]  -- list with one element
```

Note that here you will add the sum of *all* previous elements as last element. Not the sum of the last *two* elements (like Fibonacci usually does).

You also need to add a `Num x` type constraint, otherwise the type of elements of the list is not per se a numerical type, and thus you can not calculate the `sum` of these numbers.

Comment: You'll also need a `Num x` constraint to be able to use `sum`.